# What is the correct syntax for using Database.ExecuteSqlCommand with parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework 4.2 and want to call a stored procedure that has input parameters. I'm using `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` to call the stored procedure.

However, the documentation is lacking in the correct syntax for the call in order to map the parameters correctly.
My google-foo is failing me, and any help will be appreciated.

I.e. I have a procedure

```
procedure SetElementFrequency
  @ElementTypeID integer,
  @Frequency float
as ...
```

I've tried calling it with

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec SetElementFrequency @p0 @p1", 
                            elementType, frequency);
```

and

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec SetElementFrequency {0} {1}", 
                            elementType, frequency);
```

but they both fail with the error *Incorrect syntax near '@p1'.*

Comment: If this is Transact-SQL, you're missing a comma between parameters. :)

Comment: Of course it is, and of course I am :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending on your underlying database provider, you can use either of the following.

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "exec SetElementFrequency {0}, {1}",
    elementType, frequency);
```

or

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec SetElementFrequency ?, ?", elementType, frequency);
```

You may also specify `elementType` and `frequency` as [`DbParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter.aspx)-based objects to provide your own names via the [`ParameterName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter.parametername.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete MasterSmsCampaignCertificateInfo where      MasterSmsCampaignGuid = @p0 and CertificateId = @p1",
TheCampaignGuid,
certInfo.CertificateId);
```

Take a look at this similar question:
[ExecuteSqlCommand with output parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861737/executesqlcommand-with-output-parameter)
Best regards

Comment: So does this mean that the first parameter is set to `@p0`, the second to `@p1`, and so on?

Comment: Have you tried passing them as array? 
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete MasterSmsCampaignCertificateInfo where      MasterSmsCampaignGuid = @p0 and CertificateId = @p1", new object[]{
TheCampaignGuid,
certInfo.CertificateId});

Comment: It's a params parameter, so it should not matter, and yes, I've tried that too :)

Comment: This syntax works fine, the problem was in the generated query.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sql = @"Update [User] SET FirstName = {0} WHERE Id = {1}";
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, firstName, id);
```

Comment: This syntax works fine, the problem was with my query format.

Comment: This is just a copy of another answer from a similar question, without adjusting for context. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5475210/642054