# Selecting max Date from multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Is it possible to turn this into an entity framework query that will only query the database once?

```
  select max(TableADate) latestTableADate, max(TableBDate) latestTableBDate
  from
  (
      select max(a.ModifiedDate) TableADate, null TableBDate
      from TableA a

      union all

      select null, max(b.ModifiedDate)
      from TableB b
  ) data
```

The intent is to get the latest ModifiedDate from multiple tables with one sql statement so Entity Framework is not doing multiple trips to the database to get the data.

I need to know when the last time that one of the tables was updated.

**Update:**

I ended using `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery` doing the following:

```
  var output = db.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>
                  ("select data from (" +
                    "select 1 orderBy, max(ModifiedDate) data from TableA" +
                    "union all " +
                    "select 2, max(ModifiedDate) from TableB " +
                  ") temp order by orderby").ToList();


  data.TableADate = output[0];
  data.TableBDate = output[1];
```

Comment: Not sure whether you could do this with EF, but you could definitely do it by creating a `view` in the database

Comment: Yea, I was thinking that, but I wanted to see what my options are first so I can take a look at some of the pros and cons of the different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a query similar to the one you've listed using the `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). You'd need to change it to return the dates in some sort of order or use [out parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861737/executesqlcommand-with-output-parameter).