# How to return a value from a stored procedure to EF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm attempting to call a stored proc through EF and retrieve a return value from the stored proc.  I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861737/executesqlcommand-with-output-parameter#answer-6871382) answer as a guide.  Here is my stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_test]
(
    @result int OUT
)
AS
BEGIN

--DO STUFF

SET @result = 0
END
```

Here is how I'm calling it from EF:

```
var status = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "result",
    DbType = DbType.Int32,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 
};
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("EXEC usp_test @result", status);
var wasSuccessful = result.First() == 1;
if (!wasSuccessful)
{
    //DO STUFF
}
```

I'm getting this error message:

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you do a SELECT in your stored procedure? If so this is your return type. As a hint - you must consume the resultset before you can get the value of the output parameter.

Comment: @Pawel: The entire stored proc is in the question.  I also tried `SET @result = 0`.

Comment: OK. `--DO STUFF` indicated you are doing something in the body and you don't set the value of the output parameter that's why I did not know if this is a complete procedure...

Comment: @Pawel: Sorry for the confusion.  Is what I'm doing now (updated) how you set an output parameter in the SP?

Comment: I don't remember at the moment but it might be that EF always expects a resultset. Can you add a dummy `SELECT 0` to your stored proc and see if it works?

Comment: You can also change ParameterDirection.Output to ParameterDirection.ReturnValue then you don't need the select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `select @result` before end of procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_test]
(
    @result int OUT
)
AS
BEGIN

--DO STUFF

SET @result = 0
Select @result
END
```

Hope it works.

Comment: The `SELECT` at the end of the SP after setting `@result` did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to return the new id of an inserted row with a stored procedure. So I also made an OUTPUT parameter. In C# with EF6 I got it as following:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
...
db = new myEntities1();
ObjectParameter returnId = new ObjectParameter("returnId", DbType.Int64);
db.postLogItem("New item.", returnId);
MessageBox.Show("Logitem added. New returnId: " + (int)returnId.Value);
```

The name of the variable in the stored procedure needs to match the one with calling the constructor of ObjectParameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[postLogItem]
    @description nvarchar(200),
    @returnId bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.LogItem 
        (
            time,
            description
        )
        VALUES
        (
            GETDATE(),
            @description
        );

    SET @returnId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.First();` to the end...

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("EXEC usp_test @result", status).First();
```

I don't this you need `First()` here either since you're returning a single value, this would only work with an IEnumerable - but double check.

```
var wasSuccessful = result == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change ParameterDirection.Output to ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

Answer (score -3):

If nothing works then you can try this alternative approach:

1. Compute the result in PROC and save it in a table in database
2. Read the data from that table in EF code.

However, if you have a concurrent system that can run many such EF codes in parallel then ofcourse your stored proc needs become more sophisticated to handle concurrency.

Thanks, hope this might help.

Comment: This is just the type of hacky solution I typically avoid at all costs.