# How to call a SQL Server procedure using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following code in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Checking
@name NVARCHAR(200),
@password NVARCHAR(200)
AS
Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE @res int
        SELECT @res = COUNT(*)
        FROM [User]
        WHERE [User].Username = @name AND [User].PasswordHashed = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @password)
        return @res
END
```

As you can see, the procedure is returning an `Int32` value. In my C# code, I want to use this method using Entity Framework 6 and I have the following code:

```
SearchEngineEntities context = new SearchEngineEntities();
//Show the returned value by calling checking procedure in C#
```

How can I have the returning value of Checking procedure in C#? I have saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352605/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-stored-procedure-to-ef) but I was wondering if there is a direct way in Entity Framework.

Comment: have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339750/entity-framework-stored-procedure-return-value

Comment: @media because you don't care about security?

Comment: @Phill actually I care about that and that was the reason I did not use the methods that were used in the links that I brought.

Comment: Your stored proc hashes the password, and hashes without a salt, so if the database is stolen then it's pretty easy to attack the database to find passwords.

Comment: @phill thanks, actually I am aware of that but at present I'm a stage behind security. I have not written a code which does my job yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx) shows how to import and execute stored procedures with the Visual Studio Entity Data Wizard. You can figure out how to do that manually yourself from it.

**Update:** Mike has correctly put in comment that the link I shared earlier describes how to import stored procedures into Entity Framework data models.

On successful import of your stored procedure, EF will automatically generate a method in your `DbContext` extension class (`SearchEngineEntities` in your case) that corresponds to the stored procedure in your database. For your procedure, it should create a method that takes two `string` parameters and returns your `int` result encapsulated in `ObjectResult` type. Depending on your configuration it should be something like the following (not tested):

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> Checking(string name, string password)
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("Checking", name, password);
}
```

You'll be able to call the stored procedure by calling `context.Checking("name", "pass")`. Iterate over the returned `ObjectResult` to find the result your procedure has returned.

Comment: Would you bring more detail?

Comment: @media In order to use a stored procedure from entity framework, you need to import the procedure into your model.  EF will then create a function for you to call.  That link is a pretty good step by step example of adding a stored proc, and it also has a nice little description of what EF does with it.