# Out parameter with ExecuteSqlCommandAsync

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm calling a stored procedure using Entity Framework's `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` command. This throws an error message:

> Procedure or function 'LoadChargeCarrierOnForklift' expects parameter
>   '@ID_Storage', which was not supplied.

My code looks as follows:

```
SqlParameter outIdStorageParam = new SqlParameter("@ID_Storage", SqlDbType.Int) {
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
};

try {
    await Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
        "exec dbo.LoadChargeCarrierOnForklift @ID_Carrier, @ForkliftName, @User",
        new SqlParameter("@ID_Carrier", id_Carrier),
        new SqlParameter("@ForkliftName", forkliftName),
        new SqlParameter("@User", user),
        outIdStorageParam
    );
} catch (System.Exception ex) {
    var a = ex;
    throw;
}

return (int)outIdStorageParam.Value;
```

The following SQL command works, though:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @ID_Storage int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[LoadChargeCarrierOnForklift]
        @ID_Carrier = 1,
        @ForkliftName = N'ABC',
        @User = N'DEF',
        @ID_Storage = @ID_Storage OUTPUT

SELECT  @ID_Storage as N'@ID_Storage'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

What am I doing wrong with the parameter from the C# code?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871382/34092 help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
await Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
    "exec dbo.LoadChargeCarrierOnForklift @ID_Carrier, @ForkliftName, @User",
    new SqlParameter("@ID_Carrier", id_Carrier),
    new SqlParameter("@ForkliftName", forkliftName),
    new SqlParameter("@User", user),
    outIdStorageParam
```

Binds the parameters by position and omits the parameter for ID_Storage.  The equivilent of

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[LoadChargeCarrierOnForklift]
        @ID_Carrier = 1,
        @ForkliftName = N'ABC',
        @User = N'DEF',
        @ID_Storage = @ID_Storage OUTPUT
```

which binds the parameters by name, and includes two output parameters, would be

```
    SqlParameter outIdStorageParam = new SqlParameter("@ID_Storage", SqlDbType.Int) {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
    SqlParameter outReturnValue = new SqlParameter("@return_value", SqlDbType.Int) {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

    await Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
        @"EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[LoadChargeCarrierOnForklift]
            @ID_Carrier = @ID_Carrier,
            @ForkliftName = @ForkliftName,
            @User = @User,
            @ID_Storage = @ID_Storage OUTPUT",
        outReturnValue 
        new SqlParameter("@ID_Carrier", id_Carrier),
        new SqlParameter("@ForkliftName", forkliftName),
        new SqlParameter("@User", user),
        outIdStorageParam);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After adding `@ID_Storage = @ID_Storage OUTPUT` to the parameter list, it works fine. Can you teach me, why I need to do this weird @Param = @Param thing? I know, that it works, but I don't understand, why it is necessary.

Comment: That's how you bind parameters by name.  To the left of `=` is the formal parameter name, and to the right is the parameter that contains the value you are passing.  You can use the same name for both, which always looks wierd.  If you want to bind the parameters by position instead, you can, just omit the `@param = ` part and ensure you've got the parameters in the right order.